# Getting invalid date in iphone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

I am working on a project where I need show date coming from backend. I am converting backend code to correct date formate using the below code:

```
 $scope.convertedTime = function(timestamp) {
                    c=moment(timestamp).tz('America/Los_Angeles').format("MM-DD-YYYY") ;
                       var c=moment(timestamp).format("MM-DD-YYYY");

                 return c;
              };
```

When I run this code in the server in android it works fine but in IOS I am getting date field as "Invalid date".

Can anyone guide me how can I solve this issue.

Comment: It would help if you pinpointed where you get this "invalid date" error. You probably have mismatched date formats (MM-DD-YYYY is definitely not very standard. ISO would be YYYY-MM-DD, and US locale would be MM/DD/YYYY, while UK or FR locales would be DD/MM/YYYY). It's probably best for you to stick to YYYY-MM-DD everywhere, and just convert to/from the specific locale when displaying/parsing user input.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 $scope.convertedTime = function(timestamp) {
                    c=moment(timestamp).tz('America/Los_Angeles').format("MM-DD-YYYY") ;
                       var c=moment(timestamp).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
                           c = c.replace(/-/g, '/');

                 return c;
              };
```

Comment: Basically replace the '-' with '/' in your date string. You may need to do it a line or two earlier in your code depending.